# Java - Inner Classes opening a backdoor to Parent Class

Tags: java, bytecode, inner-classes

I was going through some JVM Bytecode articles when I came across this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52XMd5tCEnQ) which shows how Inner Classes open up a backdoor into the parent scope, which could be exploited? (not sure, maybe it could be?)

Here's my test code.

```
public class Outer {

    private String name = "You got me!";

    public class Inner {
        public void printName() {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Outer o = new Outer();
        Inner i =  o.new Inner();
        i.printName();
    }
}
```

Now to see if such a `backdoor` method was being created I used `javap` to look into the class files.

Here is the result, see the `printName method`

[image: ByteCode for printName method]

See the line `7:`, you will see the `invokestatic` call to a `Outer.access$0`.

Looking into the `Outer.class` we see the definition of the method.

[image: backdoor method definition]

Is this a security vulnerability? Can it be exploited? I am just curious to know more on this.

Comment: In what way is it different than a public method accessing private members?

Comment: Just mark the inner class as static to remove this reference to outer class. The inner class needs the reference because it is allowed to call methods of the outer class.

Comment: 'Vulnerability' ~ No... it's how [java lang works](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) `A static nested class interacts with the instance members of its outer class (and other classes) just like any other top-level class. In effect, a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class that has been nested in another top-level class for packaging convenience.`

Comment: @MauricePerry We have 2 separate class files for each class & the inner class is able to access the private members of the Outer class.

Comment: @AgentX the Inner class still is a nested class of Outer. I see no problem with that.

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct support for nested classes at the bytecode level, so each nested class in the Java source has to be compiled to a separate classfile. Effectively, they are completely separate, ordinary classes with some extra metadata for reflection purposes. When you access a member of the parent, the nested class needs to have access to that parent.

Normally, this is not a problem, but private members are only accessible within the class where they are defined, and hence not to the inner class. The compiler solves this by creating a bridge method that effectively changes the access level to package private.

This is a well documented phenomenon. Is it a security vulnerability? Not unless you are doing something very odd. Relying on Java's in-process sandbox is a bad idea if you care about security. But if you're working on a project that does this anyway, then yes, this is one on a long list of gotchas that you have to be aware of while coding the sandbox.

Comment: It’s worth noting that packages can be *sealed* to forbid adding other classes to the same package. Thus, if any security relevant is accessible from the same package, sealing it is a good idea…

Answer (score 2):

As you can note, synthetic accessor method has package private access. Thus when security manager is active, you cannot access it via reflection. Using `MethodHandles.lookup` you can access it from the same package only.

Comment: Why can't we access it via reflection?

Comment: Because the security manager prevents making methods *accessible* if this is not explicitly permitted. Note that you would need to *seal* a jar fil to prevent that no other library defines a class in the same package what does not longer make accessibility relevant.